# ¿Cómo ejecutar un proyecto gradle para varios entornos=

Tags: eclipse, grails, gradle

Estoy implementando un proyecto gradle con grails 3.1.6 y eclipse. Mi pregunta es la siguiente: ¿Alguien sabe cómo ejecutar un proyecto con diferentes entornos?
Tengo diferentes bases de datos definidas en el fichero application.yml según sea el entorno:

```
environments:
  developmentBDInt:
    dataSource:
        username: "usrmediacion"
        password: "pwdmediacion"
        pooled: true
        dbCreate: "update"
        driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url: "jdbc:mysql://polux:3306/mediacion?user=usrmediacion&password=pwdmediacion&sessionVariables=sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT'"
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
        properties:
            validationQuery: "SELECT 1"
            testOnBorrow: true
            testOnReturn: true
            testWhileIdle: true
            timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 1800000
            numTestsPerEvictionRun: 3
            minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 1800000
  test:
    dataSource:
        dbCreate: update
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Creo que al ejecutar el proyecto con el bootRun de Gradle a través de Eclipse me ejecuta el entorno de test y no el develpomentBDInt. Necesitaría que se ejecutara en el entorno "develompentBDInt". ¿Alguna idea de cómo se hace?

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final, después de mucho buscar, lo he encontrado.
Antes de nada, debo decir que cambié el nombre del entorno "developmentBDInt" por "development". No hace falta cambiarlo. Os lo pongo porque en el post inicial os indicaba que un entorno se llamaba "developmentBDInt". Simplemente fui haciendo pruebas hasta que encontré la solución, y una vez encontrada, había cambiado el nombre de uno de los entornos a "development" pasé de volverle a cambiar el nombre a "developmentBDInt".

Los otros entornos de la aplicación eran "test" y "production".

He añadido el siguiente código en el fichero build.gradle:

```
def loadConfiguration() {
   def environment = project.hasProperty('env') ? project.env : 'dev'
   project.ext.set 'environment', environment
}

apply from: 'environment.gradle'

subprojects {
    processResources.dependsOn setUpEnvironmentConfiguration
}
```

Además, he creado el fichero "environment.gradle" y lo he puesto en la misma carpeta donde se encuentra el fichero "build.gradle". El código del nuevo fichero es el siguiente:

```
task setUpEnvironmentConfiguration << {

    apply plugin: 'java'

    def availableEnvironments = ['development', 'test', 'production']
    def environment = project.hasProperty( 'environment' ) ? environment : 'development'

    if (!availableEnvironments.contains(environment)) {
        def message = "Target environment '${environment}' not allowed. Please use one of the following: " +
                availableEnvironments.join(", ")
        throw new TaskExecutionException(setUpEnvironmentConfiguration, new ResourceException(message))
    }

    println "***"
    println "Target environment used: '${environment}'"
    println "***"

}
```

Por último, y para indicarle a la aplicación qué entorno debe usar, se le pasa como argumentos lo siguiente:

```
-Penv=development
```

donde el valor de -Penv es el nombre del entorno.

Answer (score 0):

Como comentario inicial dada mi experiencia con versiones de grails 3.x te recomendaría no apegarte aún a un IDE. Ni eclipse (o GGTS), ni intelijj soportan muy bien las versiones de grails 3.x. Es decir, los IDEs los puedes utilizar para "codear" pero te recomendaría trabajar con grails por linea de comandos.

Dicho esto, respecto a tu pregunta, es posible cambiar las variables de entorno de grails que manejan el `environment` y colocar el que desees. En tu caso sería algo así:

Para ejecutar la aplicación:

```
$ grails -Dgrails.env=developmentBDInt run-app
```

o en caso de ejecución de tests:

```
$ grails -Dgrails.env=developmentBDInt test-app
```

La doc de grails sobre esto la podes ver [aquí](https://grails.org/wiki/Environments).

Espero sea de utilidad. Saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero necesito cambiar de entorno para debugar. En línea de comandos creo que no es posible debugar. Por eso preguntaba por si alguien sabía cómo se cambiaba de entorno en Eclipse. Saludos

Comment: No entiendo exactamente cómo estás ejecutando tu aplicación, pero eclipse en sus "Debug configurations" o "Run configurations" tiene un comando grails definido para ejecutar. En ese comando podes agregarle las conf que describo en la respuesta. Se entiende?